# Unable to resolve dependencies for assembleAndroidTest task with Android Gradle plugin 3.0.1

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin

I'm updating our project to use Gradle 4.1 and Android Gradle plugin 3.0.1. I have updated our dependency configuration to the [new configuration](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#new_configurations) and the project successfully compiles. However, there are lots of unresolved dependencies (incl. Kotlin standard library's top-level functions) when compiling android tests (`assembleAndroidTest` Gradle task). I was suspecting that Proguard might cause this (although it didn't before updating Gradle), but even adding explicit rules to keep symbols/classes doesn't help. We use Kotlin 1.2.10 and Kotlin-Kapt plugin.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use ProGuard for debug but the following answers seem useful.
I would revise your Gradle configuration another time following the migration guide, and first of all clean and invalidate caches.

### Proguard

Chech this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44253539/1009132) and [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33547643/1009132) about how to use Kotlin with Proguard.

**Disable these directives in your `build.gradle` file to discard Proguard.**

```
minifyEnabled false
shrinkResources false
```

**Configure Proguard for Kotlin.**

> You don't need to do anything special. Kotlin works with ProGuard out
>   of the box. But you may face some strange errors when processing your
>   application with ProGuard. In this case just add:
>
> ```
> -dontwarn kotlin.**
> ```

You also can add:

```
-keep class kotlin.** { *; }
-keep class kotlin.Metadata { *; }
-dontwarn kotlin.**
-keepclassmembers class **$WhenMappings {
    <fields>;
}
-keepclassmembers class kotlin.Metadata {
    public <methods>;
}
-assumenosideeffects class kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics {
    static void checkParameterIsNotNull(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String);
}
```

Check this related questions to either enable Proguard for tests or not:

[proguard gradle debug build but not the tests](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21463089/1009132)

**Specify the Proguard file to use on the instrumentation tests.**

> runProguard is old.  It was replaced with minifyEnabled
>
> With minifyEnabled (and other changes in new versions of Gradle) you
>   will may encounter issues where the Proguard config works for your
>   debug apk but not for the instrumentation tests.  The apk created for
>   instrumentation tests will use its own proguard file, so changing your
>   existing proguard file will have no effect.
>
> In this case, you need to specify the proguard file to use on the
>   instrumentation tests.  It can be quite permissive because it's not
>   affecting your debug and release builds at all.
>
> ```
>     // inside android block
>     debug {
>         shrinkResources true  // removes unused graphics etc
>         minifyEnabled true
>         proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
>         testProguardFile('test-proguard-rules.pro')
>     }
> ```

[Android Unit Tests with proguard enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26482119/1009132)

**Add a custom proguard rules file**

> **/project/app/proguard-test-rules.pro**
>
> ```
> # Proguard rules that are applied to your test apk/code.
> -ignorewarnings
>
> -keepattributes *Annotation*
>
> -dontnote junit.framework.**
> -dontnote junit.runner.**
>
> -dontwarn android.test.**
> -dontwarn android.support.test.**
> -dontwarn org.junit.**
> -dontwarn org.hamcrest.**
> -dontwarn com.squareup.javawriter.JavaWriter
> # Uncomment this if you use Mockito
> #-dontwarn org.mockito.**
> The add the following to your build.gradle for your app. To use the proguard file when testing.
>
> /project/app/build.gradle
>
> android {
>     debug {
>         minifyEnabled true
>         testProguardFile 'proguard-test-rules.pro'
>     }
> }
> ```

**Add a buidType for testing**

> I've solved this problem in my build by having an additional "dev"
>   buildType where I enable proguard, but configure it to keep all code
>   in my own package, and a few specific library classes that happen to
>   be used from tests only. I also disable obfuscation in the dev
>   buildType so that it can be debugged from an IDE.
>
> For debug and release builds I use my "real" proguard settings
>   including obfuscation and optimizations.

**Use separate test modules**

> [Separate test modules](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#test_modules) are now variant-aware. This means that
>   specifying targetVariant is no longer necessary.
>
> Each variant in the test module will attempt to test a matching
>   variant in the target project. By default, test modules contain only a
>   debug variant, but you can create new build types and new flavors to
>   create new variants to match the tested app project. A connectedCheck
>   task is created for each variant.
>
> To make the test module test a different build type only, and not the
>   debug one, use VariantFilter to disable the debug variant in the test
>   project, as shown below:
>
> ```
> android {
>     variantFilter { variant ->
>         if (variant.buildType.name.equals('debug')) {
>             variant.setIgnore(true);
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> If you want a test module to target only certain flavors or build
>   types of an app, you can use the [matchingFallbacks](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#resolve_matching_errors) property to target
>   only the variants you want to test. This also prevents the test module
>   from having to configure those variants for itself.

---

### Gradle

Revise your Gradle configuration. In order to [to build an Android project written in Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html#tarjeting-android):

- Set up the `kotlin-android` gradle plugin and apply it to your project.
- Add `kotlin-stdlib` dependencies.

> Those actions may also be performed automatically in IntelliJ IDEA /
>   AS by invoking the action:
>
> **Tools | Kotlin | Configure Kotlin in Project**

---

### kotlin-android

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.10'

    ...

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
```

---

### kotlin-stdlib

Don't forget to configure the [standard library dependency](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html#configuring-dependencies):

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib"
}
```

Revise your dependencies configuration using the [migration
guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#new_configurations).

> **Note:** `compile`, `provided`, and `apk` are currently **still available**.
>
> However, they **will be removed** in the next major release of
>   the Android plugin.

---

**Provide version manually**

> Starting with Kotlin 1.1.2, the dependencies with group
>   `org.jetbrains.kotlin` are by default resolved with the version taken
>   from the applied plugin.
>
> You can provide the version manually using the full dependency
>   notation like this:
>
> ```
> compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
> ```

---

**Resolution strategy**

You also can [force the resolution strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48000311/1009132):

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

As you are using [Android Gradle plugin 3.0.1](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#variant_aware):

```
// Instead, because the new build model delays dependency resolution, you
// should query and modify the resolution strategy using the Variant API:
android {
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.getCompileConfiguration().resolutionStrategy {
            ...
        }
        variant.runtimeConfiguration.resolutionStrategy {
            ...
        }
        variant.getAnnotationProcessorConfiguration().resolutionStrategy {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Exclude app dependencies from test configurations using the Variant API:

> On previous versions of the Android plugin, you could exclude certain
>   transitive dependencies of your app from your tests using the **exclude**
>   keyword. However, with the new dependency configurations, you must do
>   it at execution time using the Variant API:
>
> ```
> android.testVariants.all { variant ->
>     variant.getCompileConfiguration().exclude group: 'com.jakewharton.threetenabp', module: 'threetenabp'
>     variant.getRuntimeConfiguration().exclude group: 'com.jakewharton.threetenabp', module: 'threetenabp'
> }
> ```

---

**Extended versions of the Kotlin standard library**

> If you're **targeting JDK 7 or JDK 8**, you can use extended versions of
>   the Kotlin standard library which contain additional extension
>   functions for APIs added in new JDK versions. Instead of
>   `kotlin-stdlib`, use one of the following dependencies:
>
> ```
> compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7"
> compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
> ```
>
> **In Kotlin 1.1.x**, use `kotlin-stdlib-jre7` and `kotlin-stdlib-jre8`
>   instead.

---

### Kotlin reflection

> If your project uses [Kotlin
>   reflection](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect.full/index.html)
>   or testing facilities, you need to add the corresponding dependencies
>   as well:
>
> ```
> compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect"
> testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test"
> testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit"
> ```

---

### Kapt

See the description of [Kotlin annotation processing tool](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kapt.html) (`kapt`).

Apply the `kotlin-kapt` Gradle plugin:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

Comment: Proguard is not used for tests.

Comment: It should. Otherwise, how can you know your code won't crash at run-time due to a proguard issue?

Comment: Proguard is invoked when assembling your apk for release and not test build.