# Inner companion object is renamed on obfuscation and it is not accessible from other modules

Tags: android, kotlin, obfuscation

When obfuscating kotlin module the inner companion objects are renamed and are not accessible from other module though in mapping file i can see that the output object has the same name as the original one

`com.test.example.OuterClass$Configuration -> com.test.example.OuterClass$Configuration:`

Comment: Did you check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33547643/how-to-use-kotlin-with-proguard)

Comment: Proguard might remove the kotlin meta data. The class name should not matter.