# cannot retrieve class name in a kotlin fragment class

Tags: android, kotlin, classname

I am trying to get name of the class of a fragment which is a kotlin class but it returns `y0' instead of the class name

I am expecting this should return `PairEVFragment`

I will paste entire class in case I am doing anything wrong in how I create the class/fragment

```
package io.o.android.cr.ui

import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.ViewCompositionStrategy
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.viewModels
import androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.lifecycle.compose.collectAsStateWithLifecycle
import androidx.lifecycle.lifecycleScope
import androidx.lifecycle.repeatOnLifecycle
import dagger.android.support.AndroidSupportInjection
import io.o.android.cr.compose.PairEVScreen
import io.o.android.cr.model.crbd
import io.o.android.cr.repo.crRepository
import io.o.android.cr.viewmodel.PairEVViewModel
import io.o.android.navigate.Navigator
import io.o.android.navigate.ConfigureEVButtonPressed
import io.o.android.theme.oM3Theme
import io.o.android.util.extension.getPreviousFragmentName
import io.o.android.util.extension.getScreenName
import io.o.android.util.extension.hideToolbarIfInLegacyActivity
import io.o.android.util.extension.runningInLegacyActivity
import io.o.android.util.extension.showToolbarIfInLegacyActivity
import io.o.android.util.log.Reporter
import io.o.android.util.processScreenName
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import timber.log.Timber
import javax.inject.Inject

class PairEVFragment : Fragment() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory

    @Inject
    lateinit var navigator: Navigator

    @Inject
    lateinit var crRepository: crRepository

    @Inject
    lateinit var reporter: Reporter

    private val viewModel: PairEVViewModel by viewModels { viewModelFactory }

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this)
        val crbd: crbd? = arguments?.getParcelable(cr_bd)
        val startReason: ConfigureEVButtonPressed = (arguments?.getSerializable(PAIR_EV_START_REASON) as ConfigureEVButtonPressed)!!
        viewModel.onScreenCreation(crbd, startReason)
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
                viewModel.requestNavigate.collect { navigation ->
                    navigator.navigate(navigation, requireActivity())
                    viewModel.onHandledNavigationRequest()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        hideToolbarIfInLegacyActivity()
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        showToolbarIfInLegacyActivity()
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        Timber.d("xxx pairEVFragment javaClass.qualifiedName = ${this::class.qualifiedName}") // returns la.y0
        Timber.d("xxx pairEVFragment screenName = ${javaClass.simpleName.processScreenName()}") //returns y0
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        val contentView = ComposeView(requireContext()).apply {
            setViewCompositionStrategy(ViewCompositionStrategy.DisposeOnViewTreeLifecycleDestroyed)
            setContent {
                val screenState by viewModel.screenState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
                oM3Theme {
                    PairEVScreen(
                        state = screenState,
                        runningInLegacyActivity = runningInLegacyActivity(),
                        onSkip = { viewModel.onSkip() },
                        onContinue = { viewModel.onContinue() },
                        onCancelPairing = { viewModel.onCancelPairing() },
                        onSnackbarDismissed = { viewModel.onSnackbarDismissed() },
                        onHowcrApis = { viewModel.onHowcrApis() },
                        onBack = { navigator.goBack(requireActivity()) },
                        onBottomSheetClosed = { viewModel.onBottomSheetClosed() },
                        onPrivacyPolicy = {
                            try {
                                val intent = Intent(
                                    Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                                    Uri.parse("https://o-ev.com/privacy-policy/")
                                )
                                requireActivity().startActivity(intent)
                            } catch (_: Exception) {
                            }
                        })
                }
            }
        }
        return contentView
    }

    companion object {
        const val cr_bd = "cr_bd"
        const val PAIR_EV_START_REASON = "pair_ev_start_reason"
        fun newInstance(configureEVButtonPressed: ConfigureEVButtonPressed, crbd: crbd?): PairEVFragment {
            val fragment = PairEVFragment()
            val bundle = Bundle()
            bundle.putParcelable(cr_bd, crbd)
            bundle.putSerializable(PAIR_EV_START_REASON, configureEVButtonPressed)
            fragment.arguments = bundle
            return fragment
        }
    }

}
```

thanks in advance

Edit
proguard-rules.pro

```
# If you keep the line number information, uncomment this to
# hide the original source file name.
#-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile

# Firebase (see https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/start/)
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep class com.google.firebase.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.google.firebase.**
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**

# Picasso (see https://github.com/square/picasso)
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**

# Crashlytics (see https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?platform=android&authuser=1)
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-keep public class * extends java.lang.Exception
# Skip running ProGuard on Crashlytics (this is not necessary but it will speed up the builds)
-keep class com.crashlytics.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.crashlytics.**
-keep class com.google.firebase.crashlytics.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.google.firebase.crashlytics.**

# Gson (see https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/examples/android-proguard-example/proguard.cfg)
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature
-dontwarn sun.misc.**
-keep class * extends com.google.gson.TypeAdapter
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonSerializer
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer
-keepclassmembers,allowobfuscation class * {
@com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName <fields>;
}
-keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking class com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
-keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking class * extends com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken

# Reflection
-keep class kotlin.** { *; }
-keep class kotlin.Metadata { *; }
-dontwarn kotlin.**
-assumenosideeffects class kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics {
static void checkParameterIsNotNull(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String);
}
-keep class kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.builtins.BuiltInsLoader

# Classes that are serialized/deserialized using Gson
-keep class * implements io.oh.aoid.util.DTO { *; }
-keep public interface io.oh.aoid.util.DTO {*;}
-keep class * implements io.oh.aoid.util.DBObject { *; }
-keep enum * { *; }

# Dagger 2 (see https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/645)
-dontwarn com.google.errorprone.annotations.*

# MPAndroidChart (see https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Proguard)
-keep class com.github.mikephil.charting.** { *; }

# Scarlet for R8 full
-if interface * { @com.tinder.scarlet.ws.* <methods>; }
-keep,allowobfuscation interface <1>

-keepclassmembers,allowshrinking,allowobfuscation interface * {
@com.tinder.scarlet.ws.* <methods>;
}
-keep class com.tinder.scarlet.** { *; }

### Kotlin Coroutine
# https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/README.md
# ServiceLoader support
-keepnames class kotlinx.coroutines.internal.MainDispatcherFactory {}
-keepnames class kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineExceptionHandler {}
-keepnames class kotlinx.coroutines.android.AndroidExceptionPreHandler {}
-keepnames class kotlinx.coroutines.android.AndroidDispatcherFactory {}
# Most of volatile fields are updated with AFU and should not be mangled
-keepclassmembernames class kotlinx.** {
volatile <fields>;
}
# Same story for the standard library's SafeContinuation that also uses AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater
-keepclassmembernames class kotlin.coroutines.SafeContinuation {
volatile <fields>;
}
# https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.atomicfu/issues/57
-dontwarn kotlinx.atomicfu.**
-dontwarn kotlinx.coroutines.flow.**

### Kotlin
#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33547643/how-to-use-kotlin-with-proguard
#https://medium.com/@AthorNZ/kotlin-metadata-jackson-and-proguard-f64f51e5ed32
-keepclassmembers class **$WhenMappings {
<fields>;
}
-keep class kotlin.Metadata { *; }
-keepclassmembers class kotlin.Metadata {
public <methods>;
}

-keepattributes InnerClasses
-dontnote kotlinx.serialization.AnnotationsKt # core serialization annotations

# kotlinx-serialization-json specific. Add this if you have java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError kotlinx.serialization.json.JsonObjectSerializer
-keepclassmembers class kotlinx.serialization.json.** {
*** Companion;
}
-keepclasseswithmembers class kotlinx.serialization.json.** {
kotlinx.serialization.KSerializer serializer(...);
}

# Change here com.yourcompany.yourpackage
-keep,includedescriptorclasses class io.oh.android.**$$serializer { *; }o-- change package name to your app's
-keepclassmembers class io.oh.android.** { # <-- change paco name to your app's
 *** Companion;
}
-keepclasseswithmembers class io.oh.android.** { # <-- change packagome to your app's
 kotlinx.serialization.KSerializer serializer(...);
}

# uxcam integration (see https://help.uxcam.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000966252-Android-Integration)
-keep class com.uxcam.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.uxcam.**

# Kept for analytic name reporting
-keepnames class * extends io.oh.android.dagger.ui.InjectionActivityoepnames class * extends io.oh.android.dagger.ui.InjectionFragmento# Necessary to run instrumented tests on the release build
# (see https://medium.com/wix-engineering/configuring-proguard-for-android-instrumentation-tests-120d58cba155)
#

# Necessary to avoid runtime issues where the following APIs used in tests are not available

-keep class kotlin.collections.* {
public static java.util.List shuffled(java.lang.Iterable);
public static java.util.ArrayList arrayListOf(...);
}
-keep class kotlin.text.* {
public static java.lang.String substring(java.lang.String, kotlin.ranges.IntRange);
}

-keep class androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder
-keep class androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView {
public void scrollToPosition(int);
public androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder findViewHolderForPosition(int);
}

-dontwarn org.apache.commons.logging.**
-keep class org.apache.** { *; }

# Fixes issue https://programmersought.com/article/3367502760/
-dontwarn org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
-dontwarn org.xmlpull.v1.XmlSerializer
-keep class org.xmlpull.v1.* {*;}

# Without this on R8 we on release builds we get a ClassCastException cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType
-keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking class io.o.android.util.network.NetworkTask

# Retrofit for R8
 -keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking interface retrofit2.Call
 -keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking class retrofit2.Response
 -keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking class kotlin.coroutines.Continuation
```

Comment: That sounds like you have R8/ProGuard set up to obfuscate class names.

Comment: @CommonsWare thank you for getting back to me, what should I do to resolve this please

Comment: @CommonsWare I have added proguard-rules.pro file to the question, could you please suggest what needs changing

Comment: have this in proguard-rules.pro -- -keepclassmembers,allowobfuscation class * {
  @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName <fields>;
}

Comment: also added -keepnames class * extends io.ohme.android.car.ui.* but did not work. any suggestions please @CommonsWare

Comment: Personally, I don't obfuscate, as it has limited defensive value IMHO. So, I am not in position to provide you with additional advice -- sorry!

Comment: okay thank you @CommonsWare

Comment: just add @keep annotation top of PairEVFragment.

Comment: What kind of problem are you solving? Seems to me, like you use class name for debugging only

Comment: @Steyrix is right, It seems you want classname for debugging only then try `${javaClass.simpleName}` it will print your class name.

Comment: this was for reporting purposes, but noticed @keep will expose class names on release builds, so moved to hardcoded values instead of trying to know the class name

Comment: You will get your class name in `${javaClass.simpleName}` for release builds also. You can use it for reporting purpose.